# Ubuntu Wubi Booting Problems

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, 13.04, wubi

I've previously installed Windows 7 and Windows 8 and both of them in dual boot with Windows 8 bootloader. Then, I installed Ubuntu 13.04 by using Wubi in Windows 8 in a separate partition(E). So, the Windows 8 bootloader have Ubuntu listed automatically. Everything worked fine. I've deleted Windows 8 installation and switched my bootloader to Windows 7 bootmanager. But, I can't get Ubuntu 13.04 to boot. Now, it is installed in drive E and I cannot able to boot it. I've used EasyBCD and also command prompt commands to change the drive letters and paths. But, after doing this error is showing up as:

```
GRLDR is missing. Press CTRL + ALT + DELETE to restart
```

Any ideas? How can I install wubi bootloader?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `wubildr` file to be in the root of a (any) partition. You can find a copy of this in the `E:\ubuntu\winboot` directory. So copy `E:\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr` to `C:\wubildr` (this is the place the installer puts it).

For more info refer to [ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/wubildr-wubildrmbr-and-grldr](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2011/01/wubildr-wubildrmbr-and-grldr.html)